# Buttons and texts move back to original place

Tags: php, position, css-position

I have set when user types something in the search box, the suggestions will appear.

When suggestions appear, it will push the buttons and texts below down as I set its position **relative**.

But when user delete those words in the search box and the suggestion list disappears, the buttons and texts below the suggestion list did not move back to the original place.

How can I let the buttons and texts below the suggestion list **move back to the original place** when user delete those words in search box?

This is my current code:

```
<?php
include 'script_suggestion.php';
include 'script_close_suggestion_box.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Brandon's Search Engine
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #suggestion {
                border: 1px solid black;
                visibility: hidden;
                position: relative;
                background-color: transparent;
                z-index: 10;
            }
            .suggestion a {
                font-size: 12pt;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                width: 648px;
                height: auto;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .suggestion a:hover {
                background-color: #dddddd;
                width: 644px;
                padding: 2px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="search.php" name="q">
            <table align="center">
                <div>
                    <h1><center>Brandon's Search Engine</center></h1>
                </div>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="q" style="height: 27px; width: 650px; padding: 2px" placeholder="Search Now"
                           onkeyup="getSuggestion(this.value)" autocomplete="off" autoFill="on" onblur="closeBox()"/>

                    <script>document.getElementById('q').focus()</script>
                    <div id="suggestionBox" style="visibility: collapse;">
                        <div id="suggestion" style="width: 645px; text-align: left; padding: 2px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" style="height: auto; width: 60px; padding: 2px" />
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="closeBox()" style="height: auto; width: 50px; padding: 2px" />
                </div>
                <div align="center">
                    Can't find your site? <br /> Insert <a href="insert.php">here</a>.
                </div>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On your function in your onkeyup, you can check the text value and if that was empty change css position of your element to original:

```
function getSuggestion(value){
      if(!value.length()){
            //change to original place
      }
      .
      .
      .
}
```

I hope to help

Comment: In your onkeyup function what do you do? IF buttons have relative position I think when the suggestionBox has been hidden they come back to original place